# Error StarUml installation dpkg: error processing archive StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb

Tags: linux, staruml

I'm installing SarUml .
I follow those instructions:

```
wget http://staruml.io/download/release/v2.8.0/StarUML-v2.8.0-32-bit.deb
```

Then , when typing

```
sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb
```

Iget this  warning message : 
[image]

Hw can i fix it please

Comment: If the file is located in Downloads/ : `cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i ./StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb` ... I.e. if `pwd` replies with a different directory than the file location, you will have to `cd` .... or use the full path to the file.

Comment: Thank uuuuu it works

Answer (score 1):

Find the path of file StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb and give full path in following command:

sudo dpkg -i /home/usrname/StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb

It worked for me.